# vbscript : To Search a word only from the visible cells in an excel

Tags: vbscript, hiddenfield

Using vbscript, how to find/search a word in an excel only from the visible cells. i.e if a word is present in any of the hidden rows or columns, it should not return that.

Currently, i am using as below, but it returns the text irrespective of visibility. How to retrict visiblity for this?

Set foundText = excelFile.worksheets(i).Range("A1:H500").Find("Hello")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `xlCellTypeVisible` qualifier to filter only visible cells. Here's how:

```
Const xlCellTypeVisible = 12

Dim r
Set r = excelFile.Worksheets(i).Range("A1:H500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Find("Hello")

If r Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Text not found in a visible cell."
Else
    MsgBox "Text found in a visible cell."
End If
```

Comment: The above code looks like vba, I am looking for vbscript

Comment: It's VBScript. Promise.

Comment: Cool. Make sure to accept the answer to help out others in the community with a similar question.